# Schema for pg_cron when initializing the extension

Tags: postgresql, pg-cron

I'm trying to initialize the `pg_cron` extension in a dedicated schema named 'cron'.
I usually create the schema *before* creating the extension but something goes wrong in this case:

```
db_dev# CREATE SCHEMA cron;
CREATE SCHEMA

db_dev# CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron WITH SCHEMA cron;
ERROR:  schema "cron" already exists

db_dev# DROP SCHEMA cron;
DROP SCHEMA

db_dev# CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron WITH SCHEMA cron;
ERROR:  schema "cron" does not exist

db_dev# SHOW server_version;
         server_version         
════════════════════════════════
 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1)
(1 row)
```

Anything that I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. `pg_cron` will create the `cron` schema itself. There is no need to create it beforehand.